# MVC DropDownListFor item in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a ViewModel Like the following

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public List<Item> Items {get; set;}
```

and the Item class is:

```
public int ItemID {get; set;}
public bool IsMaster {get; set;}
```

In my view i have 2 inputs, a textbox for the name and a dropdownlist.

I want the dropdownlist to add an item to the list, is this possible with dropdownlistfor or do i have to pull it from the FormCollection?

Comment: Can you show in code what you want to do? It is not totally clear with "I want the dropdownlist to add an item to the list..."

Comment: I want the item the users selects in the ddl to create a new Item object and add it to the Items list

Comment: So you want the drop down list to bind directly to your Items list?  Then updates on the client (adds/removes) will bind on post so that the DDL on the client matches the Items list on the server?    The dropdown list is going to bind up to the server as the *selected value* of the DDL.  Same goes for the form collection.  In order to add to the items list, you'll have to generate an item on the server based on the selected value of the DDL in your post method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. If you have an item in your model that you can bind to the dropdownlistfor then you can get the selected item from there

```
public List<SelectListItems> Items {get;set;}
```

otherwise you have to use the form collection to get the selected value and then manually add the item. Even with the above mentioned way you would still need to manually add it to the List from the selected item.